# using awk in python in ping sweep

Tags: python, awk, subprocess, popen

I'm trying to make a ping sweep in python using subprocess but I have a problem with getting awk in Popen , I want to run this command:

> ping 192.168.1.1 -c1 | grep from | awk '{print $4 "is alive"}'
>
> output should be "assume we can receive reply form it": 192.168.1.1:is alive

here is my code "problem is in var p3"

```
import subprocess
# Ask the user for input for example we will enter 192.168.1.1
host = input("Enter a host to ping: ") 
p1 = subprocess.Popen(['ping', '-c 1', host], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p2=subprocess.Popen(["grep","from"],stdin=p1.stdout,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p3 = subprocess.Popen(["awk","\'{print $4 \"is alive\"}\'"], stdin=p2.stdout,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

# Run the command
output = p3.communicate()[0]
print (output)
```

Comment: Why do you need grep and awk for such a trivial task? Why not use Python itself?

Comment: I want to run any command using subprocess ,and I faced the awk problem so I want to know how to solve it :)

Comment: You solution is very inefficient.

Comment: I'm a beginner ,so if you can guide me to something I should check or what would be better I would be so thankful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the single quotation marks. They are necessary to delineate shell command line parameters, but not needed when there is no command line.

```
p3 = subprocess.Popen(["awk", "{print $4 \"is alive\"}"], ...)
```